# Python Crash Course exercise 8-11

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am working through the Python Crash Course book by Eric Matthes and I am stuck on 8-11. I don't quite understand how to return the new list and store it in a separate list.

So far I have tried to call the function by making a copy of the list.

```
def make_great(magicians):
    """This function adds the 'The Great' in front of a magicians name"""
    great_magicians = [] #A new list to hold names of new magicians


    while magicians: #This while loop runs while the parameter 'magicians' has elements in it
        magician = magicians.pop() #Element from magicians parameter held in magician varibale 
        great_magician = magician + " the Great" #Creating a new element to store great_magician
        great_magicians.append(great_magician) #Adding great_magicians to empty list


    for great_magician in great_magicians: #Adding elements in great_magician back into magicians
        magicians.append(great_magician)





magician_names1 = ['inho','mumbo jumbo','trick shotta','hwolla']


make_great(magician_names1[:])
```

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with your current code? What is happening, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

List are mutable, that is they can be modified. so return the modified list and save it under the variable name of - magician_names1

```
def make_great(magicians):
    """This function adds the 'The Great' in front of a magicians name"""
    great_magicians = [] #A new list to hold names of new magicians


    while magicians: #This while loop runs while the parameter 'magicians' has elements in it
        magician = magicians.pop() #Element from magicians parameter held in magician varibale 
        great_magician = magician + " the Great" #Creating a new element to store great_magician
        great_magicians.append(great_magician) #Adding great_magicians to empty list


    for great_magician in great_magicians: #Adding elements in great_magician back into magicians
        magicians.append(great_magician)

    return magicians





magician_names1 = ['inho','mumbo jumbo','trick shotta','hwolla']


magician_names1 = make_great(magician_names1[:])
print(magician_names1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current function modifies the list you pass it in place. That means if you call `make_great(magician_names1)`, it will modify the names in your main list and you won't have access to the original values any more.

If you want to make the changes in a new list, there are two general approaches you can take. The first is to change the function so that it creates and returns a new list and does not modify the list you passed in to it. That's pretty easy:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    return [magician + " the Great" for magician in magicians]
    # or:
    # results = []
    # for magician in magicians:
    # results.append(magician + " the Great")
    # return results
```

When you call it, you can assign the returned list to a new variable, and the old list will remain the same: `great_names = make_great(magician_names1)`

The other option is to leave your current function alone, as you might sometimes *want* to do the modifications in place. In the cases you don't want that, you can first make a copy, then modify the copy in place:

```
great_names = magician_names1[:]    # make a copy and give it a name
make_great(great_names)             # then modify the copied list in place
```

I'll note that while your current code *does* work for the in place modification, it's a lot more complicated than it needs to be (it also reverses the order the names appear in the list, which may be an undesireable side effect). You can write a much simpler version using the `enumerate` builtin function to get the index of a name as you iterate over the list it was contained in:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for i, name in enumerate(magicians):
        magicians[i] = name + " the Great"
```